# How to create a C# Console App Grid that groups CSV Entries by Lattitude and Longitude?

Tags: c#, csv, mapping, console-application

I'm writing a C# console application that is being used as part of a larger project that has to do with land use.  My console app needs to group entries in my CSV file using the lattitude and longitude values for each entry.  The grid grouping must be to .002 degrees specificity.

I found some sample code that will do something similar but not to the specificity needed:

```
                foreach (string[] row in reader) {
                lat = Decimal.Parse(row[latIndex]);
                lng = Decimal.Parse(row[lngIndex]);
                //TODO: do math to allow for percision of .002 rather than .001 like 
                I'm doing here
                gridID = (Math.Round(lat, 3) * 10000) + Math.Round(lng, 3);
                if (!grids.TryGetValue(gridID, out totals)) {
                    totals = new ALUGridTotals() {
                        lat = lat,
                        lng = lng
                    };

                    grids.Add(gridID, totals);
                }
```

Essentially, my question is how do I modify the Math methods in the gridID statement to use .002 degree specificity?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
private static double WeirdRounding(double n)
{
    int temp = (int)(Math.Round(n, 3) * 1000);
    return temp % 2 == 0 ? (double)temp / 1000 : ((double)temp + 1) / 1000;
}
```

I'm rounding up if it doesn't come out "even."

Edit: swapped to int, corrected goofy typo.

Comment: Instead of double, can an int be used?